# How to insert data to many to many table - room(Sql) android

Tags: java, android, mysql, kotlin, android-room

I created this table but i don't know how to add the data to the playListWithSongs table.

```html
@Entity
data class SongEntity(
  var songId : Long? = null,
  var name: String? = null,
 )
```

```html
@Entity
data class playlistEntity(
  var playListId : Long? = null,
  var playlistName: String? = null
)
```

```
@Entity
data class playListWithSongs(
     var playlistId: Long,
     var songId: Long
)
```

Here How to insert the ids to the playListWithSongs table?

But in my case, the playlist may have the same songs or empty. Even songs will be present in one playlist , no playlist or many playlist so how can I insert the PlayListWithSongs Entity. Since both ids are primary key and I will have zero songs for a playlist there will be null and contains duplication (Here the list of song and list of course Size are not similar)

```
@Insert
fun insert(playListSong: playListWithSongs)

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertPlayList(playList: PlayListEntity?)

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertCourse(song: SongsEntity?)

@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM playListEntity")
fun getAll(): LiveData<List<PlayListWithSong>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define the return type of the insert functions as `Long` in all of your `dao` classes, you will be able to get the id of the inserted item, then use this id for inserting in `PlayListWithSongs`. For example:

```
@Dao
interface SongDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(entity: Song): Long
}
```

#### Update:

Note that the `Song` and the `Playlist` are two distinct entities. So, while you want to assign a `Song` to a `Playlist` (which means adding a new row in `playListWithSongs` containing both their ids), the target song and playlist should exist in db.

I mean you would never try to add a song to a playlist which has not existed yet. So, At the first moment that a playlist gets created, there is no song assigned to it. It means that there is no row in the `playListWithSongs` table with the `playlistId` of the newly created one.

To sum up, it is obvious that when you want to assign a song to a playlist, you should have both ids. Also, it's better to not to use this couple as the primary key for the `playListWithSongs`. Let's see my written code for this subject:

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "playListWithSongs",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Song::class,
            parentColumns = ["songId"],
            childColumns = ["songId"],
            onDelete = CASCADE
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Playlist::class,
            parentColumns = ["playlistId"],
            childColumns = ["playlistId"],
            onDelete = CASCADE
        )
    ],
    indices = [
        Index(
            value = ["songId", "playlistId"],
            unique = true
        )
    ]
)
data class PlayListWithSongs(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "songId") val songId: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "playlistId") val playlistId: Long
)
```

As you can see in the above code, if a song or playlist gets removed, all of its assignments on `playListWithSongs` get removed too (due to `CASCADE`). So there is no concern about unused rows and duplication (Note that the combination of songId and playlistId is defined as unique).

Comment: But in my case, the playlist may have the same songs or empty. Even songs will be present in one playlist , no playlist, or many playlists so how can I insert the PlayListWithSongs Entity.

Comment: Since both ids are primary key and I will have zero songs for a playlist there will be null and contains duplication (Here the list of song and list of course Size are not similar)

Comment: @14Programming: I've updated the answer. Please check it out.

Comment: Thank you so much @aminography But I'm having doubt like what will happen when we insert a playlist with multiple lists of songs . For Example 

PlayListId.  --------->.  SongId
   1                  ------>               15
   2                  ------->               15
   1                   ----->              100

Here the ids will get duplicated right?

Comment: I'd recommend you to trust on this structure:) Each playlist can have zero to any number of songs. In addition, each song can belong to zero to any number of playlists. It provides the many-to-many relation correctly without any duplications. Note that duplication means repeated pairs of [playlistId, songId] like [1, 5] and [1, 5] which could not be existed due to                                                                                 `Index(value = ["songId", "playlistId"], unique = true )`.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again @aminography. My Insertion is successful but when I fetch data from db Im getting null

Comment: No problem, feel free. Please share the code on insertion and retrieval.

Comment: Is the name of table correct in `@Query("SELECT * FROM playListEntity")`? For example in my answer, I set it `playListWithSongs` according to the `tableName = "playListWithSongs"`.

Answer (score 0):

OTOH, You can do it without mapping. Create two entity one for songs another one for playlist with songs, instead of mapping keep the song id's as a list object in the playlist, and query the song table with the id's from the playlist accordingly. Here is how you can achieve that - https://medium.com/@toddcookevt/android-room-storing-lists-of-objects-766cca57e3f9.

Nevertheless, I do prefer the conventional mapping as **@aminography** eloborated in his answer so that u can make use of `CASCADE` action to propagate the delete or update operation on the parent key to each dependent child key.